# JS crashes on chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

Im trying to make a js game using canvas as an assignment. I am supposed to draw ants on canvas and they were supposed to go for the food. My code works to an extend. For some reason only one of the bugs go for the food but the real problem is that after eating two food objects and while the ant is going for the third, the js just crashes. Timer stops, my buttons stop working. I am really confused and cant figure out why its doing that. Im calling requestAnimationFrame to move the ants and the function I keep calling to move them is this:

```
function repeatOften() {
  var cur_time = Date.now();
  var delta_time = (cur_time - last_frame) / 1000;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //update each bug
  for (var i = 0; i < bugArray.length; i++) {
    if (foodArray.length != 0) {
      bugArray[i].cur_target = foodArray[0];
      var shortest_dist = Math.sqrt(((foodArray[0].xpos - bugArray[i].xpos) * (foodArray[0].xpos - bugArray[i].xpos)) + ((foodArray[0].ypos - bugArray[i].ypos) * (foodArray[0].ypos - bugArray[i].ypos)));

      for (var a = 0; a < foodArray; a++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(((foodArray[a].xpos - bugArray[i].xpos) * (foodArray[a].xpos - bugArray[i].xpos)) + ((foodArray[a].ypos - bugArray[i].ypos) * (foodArray[a].ypos - bugArray[i].ypos))) < shortest_dist) {
          bugArray.cur_target = foodArray[a];
          shortest_dist = Math.sqrt(((foodArray[a].xpos - bugArray[i].xpos) * (foodArray[a].xpos - bugArray[i].xpos)) + ((foodArray[a].ypos - bugArray[i].ypos) * (foodArray[a].ypos - bugArray[i].ypos)));
        }
      }

      // go towards the cur_target
      if ((((bugArray[i].xpos - bugArray[i].cur_target.xpos) >= 0) && ((bugArray[i].xpos - bugArray[i].cur_target.xpos) < 10)) && (((bugArray[i].ypos - bugArray[i].cur_target.ypos) >= 0) && ((bugArray[i].ypos - bugArray[i].cur_target.ypos) < 10))) {
        removeFood(bugArray[i].cur_target);
      }

      if ((bugArray[i].xpos - bugArray[i].cur_target.xpos) > 0) {
        bugArray[i].xpos -= bugArray[i].speed * delta_time;
      } else if ((bugArray[i].xpos - bugArray[i].cur_target.xpos) < 0) {
        bugArray[i].xpos += bugArray[i].speed * delta_time;
      }

      if ((bugArray[i].ypos - bugArray[i].cur_target.ypos) > 0) {
        bugArray[i].ypos -= bugArray[i].speed * delta_time;
      } else if ((bugArray[i].ypos - bugArray[i].cur_target.ypos) < 0) {
        bugArray[i].ypos += bugArray[i].speed * delta_time;
      }
    }
    //draw foods

    for (var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
      drawFood(foodArray[i]);
    }
  }

  //update time

  time -= delta_time;
  last_frame = cur_time;
  var timespan = document.getElementById("time");
  timespan.innerHTML = Math.round(time) + " seconds";
  if (Math.round(time) == 0 || foodArray.length == 0) {
    DisplayScore();
    pause();
  } else {
    drawBugArray();
    GlobalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
    if (Math.round(time) % ((Math.round(Math.random() * 300) + 1)) == 0) {
      spawnBug();
    }
  }
}
```

my drawfood and drawbugarray functions just draws on canvas the template for the foods and bugs, and my remove food function is as follows:

```
function removeFood(food) {
  for (var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
    if (foodArray[i] == food) {
      var temp = foodArray[i];
      foodArray[i] = foodArray[foodArray.length - 1];
      foodArray.pop();
      return temp;
    }
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for (var a = 0; a < foodArray.length; a++) {`?

Comment: Thats right thanks :D But that didnt cause the problem

Comment: Open the Javascript debugger, and click on the pause button when it's about to crash, so you can see where the code is stuck.

Comment: I debugged it and put some of the arrays and time on the watchlist however after 6-7 seconds or so all the arrays and variables become "not available"

Comment: Try making `ctx` a global variable, or at least outside the repeat often code. At the moment a new "2d" context is being created 50-60 times a second.

Comment: Thanks, that wasnt the solution however

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys! Apparently drawing all the foods for each bug was the problem i took it outside the "for (var i = 0; i < bugArray.length; i++){}" loop and it fixed it